# How to handle onError for img tag in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am simply  don't know how many images will there on cdn folder so i am looping whenever i get onerror for image i will stop the adding the images tag. but even a(as variable) changing to true loop is looping till 13 not stoping over 10 because there are only 10 images in folder. i also want to add pop up for each so adding num but only  last index attaching on images.

```
componentDidMount() {
    let images = [];
    let src = [];
    var a = false;
    let commonPath = filesPath + "companyImages/";
    let num = 1;
    let companyId = this.props.tab.Id;
    while (a !== true && num < 13) {
        if (a == true) {
            alert("I am breaking")
            break;
        }
        let imageFolder = `${companyId}/${companyId}_00${num}.jpg`;
        let fullPath = `${commonPath}${imageFolder}`;
        let tag = <img src={fullPath} height={140} key={num} id={'image' + num} width={200} className="image" onClick={() => this.openImage(num)} onError={a = true} onLoad={() => { console.log(num,"yup")}}></img>;
       
        images.push(tag);
        src.push(fullPath);
        num++;

    }
   
    this.setState({allImages:images,allSrcs:src});
}
```

Comment: Can you not have some JSON describing the images/location that you could then `map` over?

Comment: @Andy           no client can post many images in folder so i don't have any control.

Comment: I take it the CDN used has no public api?

Comment: Have you tried using an arrow function for `onerror`? `onerror={() => a = true}`

Comment: Though I feel like this is actually related to the way an img src is loaded. I would assume it's asynchronous, in some sense, so the onerror is not fired until some time later.

Comment: @MattU          Yes I tried but did not work ,  main weird  thing i `alert(a)` it is showing true but loop is not stopping and yes i also think this can be reason so  better way to handle this ?

Comment: @Squiggs.       yes , it has no public api.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
const images = [];
const imageLoad = () => {
  const img = new Image();
  let imageFolder = `${companyId}/${companyId}_00${images.length}.jpg`;
  let fullPath = `${commonPath}${imageFolder}`;
  img.addEventListener('load',() => {
    images.push(img.src);
    imageLoad();
  })
  img.addEventListener('error',() => {
    images.map((img,i) => `<img src="${img.src}" data-key="${num}$ id="image${i} className="image"/>`);
    // add the images to the DOM here
  }
  img.src=fullPath;       
};
imageLoad()
```

and then delegate the click and set the height and width in CSS